# Invocable method giving error in FSL flow mobile

Tags: apex, invocable-method, field-service-lightning

I created a flow using Flow designer and it is a FSL mobile flow. Here I basically uploading a file and then using the same for Einstein Prediction and here is how I'm doing.

1. Upload file using fileUpload component in Flow.
2. Get the uploaded file's **ContentDocumentId** using *Get Records* block
3. Using this *ContentDocumentId* I'm getting the **Content Version** and storing it into a variable (type = Content Version Record), and passing it to my Apex Invocable Method.

Here comes my problem.

when I have the below code.

```
@InvocableMethod
    public static List<String> test_getAccountIds(List<ContentVersion> Input) {
        List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
        accountIds.add('Hi');
        return accountIds;
    }
```

It is returning `Hi` to my flow back with out any error. where as my other code(which is what I need).

```
@InvocableMethod
    public static List<String> test_getAccountIds(List<ContentVersion> Input) {
        List<String> accountIds = new List<String>();
        System.debug('Content Data is '+Input[0].VersionData);
        System.debug(Input.size());
        EinsteinVision_Probability res;

        Blob fileBlob = Input[0].VersionData;
        EinsteinVision_PredictionService service = new EinsteinVision_PredictionService(myKey);
        EinsteinVision_Dataset[] datasets = service.getDatasets();
        for (EinsteinVision_Dataset dataset : datasets) {
            System.debug('dataset.Name'+dataset.Name);
            if (dataset.Name.equals('houses2')) {
                EinsteinVision_Model[] models = service.getModels(dataset);
                EinsteinVision_Model model = models.get(0);
                EinsteinVision_PredictionResult result = service.predictBlob(model.modelId, fileBlob, '');
                EinsteinVision_Probability probability = result.probabilities.get(0);
                res=probability;
            }
        }
        System.debug('label is '+res.label);        

        accountIds.add(res.label);
        //System.debug(accountIds);
        System.debug(accountIds.size());
        return accountIds;
    }
```

It gives me error as `Unable to load Flow Definition`. It doesn't even start the flow.

please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Seems "Run Flows" permission is missing for logged-in User's Profile.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Apex classes aren’t supported in the flows when access through Field Service Mobile App.

Here you can find more limitations in the document - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mfs_flow_considerations.htm&type=5